# how to add a relative layout inside a listview in transparent to the bottom of the listview

Tags: java, android

I have a list view in my app and to the bottom of the list view i need to add to buttons but it should be above that the listview with less colored transparent background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Used `RelativeLayout` what's wrong with that???

Comment: I guess User is looking for floating toolbar that floats on bottom above Listview..

Comment: when i add the layout using drag and drop it will automatically going out of the list view

Comment: Chintan Soni you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` to render the buttons on top on the list. I also suggest using `android:layout_above="@+id/your_button"` on your `listview` so that you don't block any elements.

Answer (score 0):

This will work well for you, I guess:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llbutton"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1"
        />

        <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 2"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```